# Не работает вызов MAX(id) sqlite в python (?)

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Есть ДБ с постами созданная по схеме

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  title TEXT NOT NULL,
  description TEXT NOT NULL,
  content TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

inint_db.py код:

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('database.db')


with open('schema.sql') as f:
    connection.executescript(f.read())

cur = connection.cursor()

cur.execute("INSERT INTO posts (title, content, description) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
            ('First Post', 'Content for the first post', 'Description content for the first post')
            )

cur.execute("INSERT INTO posts (title, content, description) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
            ('Second Post', 'Content for the second post', 'Description content for the second post')
            )

cur.execute("INSERT INTO posts (title, content, description) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
            ('Third Post', 'Content for the third post', 'Description content for the third post')
            )

cur.execute("INSERT INTO posts (title, content, description) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
            ('4 Post', 'Content for the 4 post', 'Description content for the 4 post')
            )

connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

Вызываю через python самый последний пост

```
import sqlite3


def get_db_connection():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    return conn



conn = get_db_connection()
posts = conn.execute('select MAX(id) from posts;').fetchall()
#posts = conn.execute('SELECT * FROM posts').fetchall()
conn.close()
posts=posts
```

Но не могу ни чего получить из этого самого последнего поста.
Вот этот код вызывает ошибку:

```
print(posts['title'])
```

ошибка:
File "C:\Users\windo\Desktop\Site_working_ver 0.1\HTML\test-sql.py", line 16, in 
print(posts['title'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Может я изначально пошел не правильно. Мне надо вызвать последние три поста и разместить их на странице html с данными title description created. Помогите пожалуйста, я все ни как не пойму как это сделать

[Вот здесть смотрел создание БД](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-make-a-web-application-using-flask-in-python-3-ru)

Comment: `fetchall` возвращает список котрежей, а не словарь. покажите вашу "голову" таблицы, чтобы можно было понять под каким индексом в кортеже какой столбец находиться.

Comment: @n1tr0xs Голова это что?

Comment: заголовок таблицы, в котором пишутся названия столбцов

Comment: @n1tr0xs я обновил пост

Comment: @n1tr0xs это же надо было?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть такой вариант:

```
import sqlite3


def get_db_connection():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    return conn


posts_count = 3

conn = get_db_connection()
max_id = conn.execute('select MAX(id) from posts;').fetchall()[0]['MAX(id)'] # получаем id последнего поста
ids = str(tuple(range(max_id-posts_count+1, max_id+1))) # делаем список подходящих id
posts = conn.execute(f'select title, description, created from posts where id in {ids}').fetchall() # получаем последние posts_count постов
conn.close()

for post in posts:
    print(post['title'], post['description'], post['created'])
```

Или так:

```
import sqlite3


def get_db_connection():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    return conn


posts_count = 3

conn = get_db_connection()
max_id = conn.execute('select MAX(id) from posts;').fetchall()[0]['MAX(id)'] # получаем id последнего поста
posts = conn.execute(f'select title, description, created from posts where id between {max_id-posts_count+1} and {max_id}').fetchall() # получаем последние posts_count постов
conn.close()

for post in posts:
    print(post['title'], post['description'], post['created'])
```

Однако, это можно сделать и средствами `sql`:

```
import sqlite3


def get_db_connection():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    return conn


posts_count = 3

conn = get_db_connection()
posts = conn.execute(f'''
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT {posts_count}
    ) sub
    ORDER BY id ASC
''').fetchall()
conn.close()

for post in posts:
    print(post['title'], post['description'], post['created'], sep='\t')
```